# How to store my API key in my iOS app so I can release my app to the App Store?

Tags: swift, xcode, api, api-key

I'm new to iOS development. I am using this API and I have to use the API key. How do I store my API key on my iOS device? Then I can plan for a release the app to the app store. My concern is using reverse engineering, if I hardcode my API key, people can retrieve my API key. So, any suggestions please?

Comment: You can save it in plist file.

Comment: Do you need to transmit this API Key in the clear as part of your requests? If so, an attacker wouldn't even need to reverse engineer your app, they would simply sniff your network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can obfuscate such API key string into your code, check the following

https://github.com/rockbruno/swiftshield

https://github.com/pjebs/Obfuscator-iOS

https://github.com/Polidea/SiriusObfuscator